# SDL runtime binaries, what are they used for?

Tags: c++, linker, runtime, sdl

I am following a tutorial that takes me to this SDL page (https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). In there, I can see three things I can download:

- Source code
- Runtime Binaries
- Development libraries

I am trying to make sense out of them. My understanding is this:

- Source Code: Is the original code made by the creator of the SDL, not compiled into a library.
- Runtime Binaries: I have no idea
- Development libraries: Is the code but this time compiled into libraries. There are two versions because one was compiled in a way that works with the VC (Visual compiler) and the other one is compiled in a way that works with the gcc compiler.

What are the runtime binaries for?
I imagine these thee scenarios:

- Source Code: I am writing my project and when I hit compile I compie what I wrote alone with the SDL source code.
- Runtime binaries: ?
- Development libraries: I set up my programming environment to recognize the libraries. Then I write my code and when I hit compile the compiler compiles my code and then the linker links my code and the SDL libraries together into an executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The runtime binaries / libraries are the files that your application needs to use at run-time to access the library functions. They are the files that contain the actual compiled code of the library that your application will call when it is executed.

Comment: Ah so then the development libraries option download package will have the runtime libraries plus other things. Then the runtime binaries option is for those that just want to download the .dll that is needed for the application to work, but they don't necessarily want to develop. Gotcha.
I am looking the different files that each download provides. Ill google more about them and maybe I can find more info about that too.
Thanks!

Comment: @Hai "so then the development libraries option download package will have the runtime libraries plus other things" - Yes.